# Parsing of file with Key value in C/C++

Tags: c++

Need some help in parsing the file

```
Device#  Device Name                 Serial No.                  Active Policy         Disk#         P.B.T.L        ALB
                                                                     Paths                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------
 1       AB      OPEN-V-CM           50 0BC1F1621                          1    SQST           Disk  2       3.1.4.0         N/A
 2       AB      OPEN-V-CM           50 0BC1F1605                          1    SQST           Disk  3       3.1.4.1         N/A
 3       AB      OPEN-V*2            50 0BC1F11D4                          1    SQST           Disk  4       3.1.4.2         N/A
 4       AB      OPEN-V-CM           50 0BC1F005A                          1    SQST           Disk  5       3.1.4.3         N/A
```

The above information is in devices.txt file and and i want to extract the device number corresponding to the disk no i input. 
The disk number i input is just an integer (and not "Disk  2" as shown in the file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int wantedDisknum = 4;
    int finalDeviceNum = -1;

    ifstream fin("test.txt");

    if(!fin.is_open())
        return -1;

    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        string line;
        getline(fin, line);
        stringstream ss(line);

        int deviceNum;
        ss >> deviceNum;
        if(ss.fail())
        {
            ss.clear();
            continue;
        }

        string unused;
        int diskNum;
        ss >> unused >> unused >> unused >> unused >> unused >> unused >> unused >> diskNum;

        if(diskNum == wantedDisknum)
        {
            finalDeviceNum = deviceNum;
            break;
        }
    }

    fin.close();
    cout << finalDeviceNum << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the file and skip first 3 lines.
Start reading line by line from 4th line onward. You can get the device number easily as it is the first column.
To get the disk no, search through each line using the *space character*. When you encounter one space character it means you've gone past one column. **Ignore the repeated spaces** and continue this until you reach the disk no. You must handle the spaces in the column data separately if it exist.

Load the disk no and device no in to say a map and later you can use your input to query the device info from this map.

Comment: Thanks Ragesh, Since the key value that i have is of Disk# and not the device# and the device# comes at the start of each row. I am wondering if i have to keep the device# in a temp variable till the end of the line if found return that device# else proceed with the next line. Do u think its a good way?  I am not aware of map so dont know how to go about it.

Comment: Read the whole file at the start and load it in to a data structure, say an array of structure containing both disk# and device# or a map if the disk# is unique. You can search in the array or lookup in the map using the disk# when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX, you can easily achieve this using awk or other script lang.

```
cat Device.txt | awk '{if ( $1 == 2 ) print}'
```

In C++, you have to extract specific column using `strtok` and compare it with 'val' if it matches print that line.'

Comment: Yup i will try using strtok to get each row. Also can anyone pls help me with the sample code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no "Disk" in any of the following columns:

1) Skip lines until you encounter '-' as the first character of a line, then skip that line too.

2) read a line

2.a) skip characters of the current line until isdigit(line[i]) function returns true, then read current character and characters following it into a temporary buffer until isdigit(line[i]) returns false. This is the device id.

2.b)  Skip characters of the current line until you find a 'D'

2.b.i) match 'i', 's', 'k' characters, if any of them fails, go to 2.b

2.c) skip characters of the current line until isdigit(line[i]) function returns true, then read current character and characters following it into another buffer until isdigit(line[i]) returns false. This is the disk id.

3) print out both buffers

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Regular Expression cheat sheet handy, but I'm pretty sure it would be straightforward to run each line in the file through a regex that:

1) looks for a integer in the line
2) skips whitespace followed by text three times
3) matches characters one space and characters

Boost, Qt, and most other common C++ class libraries have a Regex parser for just this kind of thing.